# pacemaker with two nodes on different subnet

Tags: pacemaker

I have a cluster with 2 Nodes running on different subnets. They both communicate but I have always one node offline

`node 1` : mon0101 is online and mon0201 is offline
`node 2` : mon0101 is offline and mon0201 is online

IP of node 1 is : 10.1.18.115 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.1.18.254
IP of node 2 is : 10.2.18.115 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.2.18.254
Nodes are distants and we use a vpn to communicate.

EDIT : the purpose of this configuration is a monitoring system in redundant distributed architecture. We have 2 Central Server collecting informations one in primary mode and the other in secondary mode. When the primary is dead, pacemaker/corosync do the job and we can keep activities alive.
Servers are on two different place communicating by vpn.

EDIT 2 : As asked my conf files and some results : 
[My cluster.conf content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THui8.png) 
[My pcs status result on node 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIXDc.png)
[My pcs status result on node 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHfXi.png)
[My cman_tool result on node 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Wpb.png)
[My cman_tool result on node 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs2da.png)
[My pcs cluster status on node 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeV5Z.png)
[My pcs cluster status on node 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2XQO.png)
Multicast is enabled on my SonicWall both on firewall & VPN settings 
If I use this config on node on the same networks everything run fine, both nodes are online and failover is a success.

Comment: Are you sure pacemaker/crm is connecting? Because if both of them show the other node as down, it seems in fact they are _not_ communicating. What is the purpose of this setup? It seems errorprone, at minimum.

Comment: I agree with Lenniey, you shouldn't try stretching Pacemaker across distances/networks without understanding all the implications of doing so. Boothd (from SUSE) is something you might want to look into if you do intend to stretch your cluster across distances/networks.

Comment: It's all the problem, when i try "service pacemaker status" on both node, it's listening, same thing for corosync, but they don't communicate across the network.

Comment: If you really want to keep this setup, the configs _and_ logs of both nodes would be helpful. Unicast, multicast, etc., all of these settings can be broken by a VPN.